# how an application sniff the wifi traffic on android?

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-bluetooth, wifimanager, android-wireless

I want to implement an android application that sniff the wifi and bluetooth traffic all the time and execute some actions when it detects some types of frames or messages.

Comment: That should not be possible, except perhaps on rooted devices, and even then I am somewhat skeptical.

Comment: it is not possible to see the traffic received by the wireless devise?